# Find the upper and lower limits of the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Finding the results (4.1) (4.2) (4.3) was really easy.
But it's hard to understand what lines in the red box function or work in this solution.

What I understood about lines in the red box is that
if there are infinitely many odds and evens, then it is not Cauchy, and
if there are either only infinitely many odds or evens, then it is Cauchy.

I don't even get what this assumption means. I think there are infinitely many odds and evens in n...

How is proving if it is Cauchy or not related with finding the upper and lower limits of the sequence?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the reals are a complete metric space, a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy.  When finding upper and lower limits of a sequence, we only consider the set of all convergent subsequences.  Thus, if a subsequence is not Cauchy, it does not converge, so we ignore it.

The solution is saying that there are only two values to which a subsequence can converge, so these must be the lower and upper limits.